# How to handle 'animation was deprecated in iOS 15.0' inside if statement

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an iOS application (using SwiftUI) that uses the `.animation` modifier in the deprecated way. I know nowadays we have to use the extra value argument but I wonder how to handle it in next situation? We have an animation inside a conditional view like this:

```
struct SomeExampleView: View {
    
    // Properties
    // ...
    
    var body: some View {
        let message = self.someState.messages.first { $0.seen != true }
        
        return ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            ScrollView {
                // Content
                // ...
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            if message != nil {
                VStack {
                    HStack(alignment: .top) {
                        Text(message!.title)
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            // Handle tap: the message will be marked as 'seen', when other unseen messages are available the next one will show (see first line in body)
                            // ...
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        }
                    }
                    Text(message!.message)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 140)
                .transition(.asymmetric(
                    insertion: .move(edge: .top),
                    removal: .move(edge: .top)
                ))
                .animation(.default)
            }
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

I tried several ways like a state property which is modified with the `.onAppear()` and `.onDisappear()` modifiers without success, the animation is not executed (I believe because of the if statement).

Comment: What it animates and on which condition?

Comment: I would try putting `withAnimation` in the Button action.

Comment: @Asperi: it animates the VStack representing an unseen message inside the if statement, it should slide down when the first unseen message appears and slide up when it disappears (by clicking the button a message is marked as seen, if another unseen message is available this will be the next one shown)

Comment: Fixed it with @ChrisR solution to put the `withAnimation` in the Button action. I also added the `withAnimation` in `onAppear` of the ZStack and moved the message variable to a property with the `@State` property wrapper. Everything works expect for the first message shown: there is no animation when the first message shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell in the animation modifier which `@State` variable you are trying to animate. You can add multiple animation modifiers too.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var makeBigger = 1.0

    var body: some View {
        Button("Press here") {
            makeBigger += 1
        }
        .scaleEffect(makeBigger)
        .animation(.linear(duration: 3), value: makeBigger) // -> here
    }
}
```